# Generate seamless textures that can be UV-mapped ramdomly

Tags: textures, procedural-generation

I want to test procedural texture generation for [one of my projects](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/197429/transforming-3d-coordinates-to-2d-isometric-position), my goal is to use those generated textures with random UV-mapping in order to avoid noticeable texture repetition.

For purely random textures is simple and straightforward, imagine the texture below as the the top of Minecraft-like grass block:

[image]

With texture repetition looks pretty bad:

[image]

But with a bigger texture and UV-mapping randomly, repetition is not as noticeable:

[image]

And if I add rotation and/or make the texture bigger (so I can scatter the mapping more) it would be even better, also as a bonus i can move the grass/dirt line for biome variations or gradients:

[image]

The problem with this technique<sup>1</sup> is that this only works with this "*pixel soup*" since it doesn't have any noticeable pattern it shows a decent result no matter what the UV-mapping is.

But for images with a pattern it only works as long as the pattern follows strict rules; in the example below green-pink and blue-red points should always connect.

[image]

And the random UV-mapping should always be set in a way that the green-pink and blue-red points are picked (the UV coordinates should be a multiple of a *chunk*), that might be good enough but I wonder if there's a way to improve this generation, can I do something that relaxes the rules I've mentioned before?

Specifically I'm asking:

- A seamless texture can be created without forcing *chunk* patterns to match borders or with more freedom matching *chunk* patterns?
- The texture can be created in a way that every *chunk* would match in more ways: instead of every *chunk*, every ½*chunk* ¼*chunk* (even if it is only in one axis)?

---

<sup>1</sup>Does it have a name? It would be very useful to know in order to search documentation about it.

Comment: Recommended related question: [How can I design good continuous (seamless) tiles?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/26152/33287)

Comment: A layered block-based generation strategy with the wave collapse technique (mentioned in [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/188721/33287)) might be of use.

Comment: What you have created in the last example appears to actually be a tileset of 16 tiles which all connect to each other. And then you used that tileset to create a tiled map by placing hem at random.

Comment: @Philipp that's correct, but I feel like this is more rigid than it need to be and maybe someone with more experience (or imagination) can suggest a better way (better = more freedom to match tiles) to achieve the same.

Comment: You may be interested in [this technique to help preserve variance when blending randomly-splatted texture patches](https://github.com/Error-mdl/UnityGaussianTex). It works by transforming the source texture to have a Gaussian histogram that blends in a well-behaved fashion, and storing the transformation used so it can be undone after blending. It won't solve the structure problem you've pointed out, but for somewhat noisy/naturalistic textures it performs quite well. For structured patterns, the best option I know is randomized Wang tiles - is that too restrictive?

Comment: I posted about this on the PROCJAM Discord, and folks there suggested [this simplification/improvement of the above technique](https://medium.com/@jasonbooth_86226/stochastic-texturing-3c2e58d76a14), which works particularly well for heightmap textures, and this [slightly tangentially related paper about using Wang tiles for fast blue noise](https://johanneskopf.de/publications/blue_noise/).